# Desktop images out of order since updating to High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, desktop

I Just updated to High Sierra. I have a folder with file names like desktop-0001.jpg, desktop-0002.jpg, and so on that is used to change my desktop image every minute. In System Prefs the image order appears to be random and doesn't follow the file names like it always has. I tried using the `touch` command on all files, hoping to give them all the same modified time so the filename would take over the order, but the new random order remained. This is a Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2015. I also have an older iMac where the problem does not exist. Ideas?